# how to wrap the line of code in xcode with a hotkey?

Tags: swift, xcode, hotkeys

let say i have this code:

`plane.materials = gridMaterial`

and I want the gridMaterial to be enclosed with `[]`. Is there a hotkey to just highlight the gridMaterial and press the hotkey? Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Xcode` (top menu) -> `Settings` -> `Text Editing` -> `Editing`. Then check the box in front of `Enclose selection in matching delimiters`.

After that highlight what ever the are in your code and press`[`.

Comment: this totally works! thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi happy to help you. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. Thank you

Comment: hi @udi, another question.  is there a shortcut to remove and symbol of an enclosed code?    

lets say: [gridMaterial] and i want to remove the [] after I highlight the [gridMaterial].  basically to remove the enclosing symbol.

Comment: no idea. Ask a separate question. Someone will answer